# How can I use shorthand if else statement in my js code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created the following if else statement but there are so many if else statement. I want to learn how can I make it shorthand?

```
if(REL == 'Like'){
   $('#Like' + dataid).attr('rel', 'NotLike');
} else if(REL == 'Love') {
   $('#Love' + dataid).attr('rel', 'NotLove');
} else if(REL == 'Unbelievable'){
   $('#Unbelievable' + dataid).attr('rel', 'NotUnbelievable');
} else if(REL == 'Spectacular'){
   $('#Spectacular' + dataid).attr('rel', 'NotSpectacular');
} else if(REL == 'Emotional'){
   $('#Emotional' + dataid).attr('rel', 'NotEmotional');
}
```

Comment: Look into a case switch

Comment: `$('#' + REL + dataid).attr('rel', 'Not' + REL);`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just take the variable with a check.

```
if (['Like', 'Love', 'Unbelievable', 'Spectacular', 'Emotional'].indexOf(REL) !== -1) {
    $('#' + REL + dataid).attr('rel', 'Not' + REL);
}
```

For a flip-flop based on strings starting with `'Not'`, you may use this

```
var temp = REL,
    not = 'Not';

if (REL.substring(0, 3) === 'Not') {
    temp = REL.substring(3);
    not = '';
}
if (['Like', 'Love', 'Unbelievable', 'Spectacular', 'Emotional'].indexOf(temp) !== -1) {
    $('#' + REL + dataid).attr('rel', not + temp);
}
```

Proposal with state saver

```
var lastState = '';

function change(state) {
    var temp = state,
        not = 'Not';
    if (state.substring(0, 3) === 'Not') {
        temp = state.substring(3);
        not = '';
    }
    if (['Like', 'Love', 'Unbelievable', 'Spectacular', 'Emotional'].indexOf(temp) !== -1) {
        $('#' + temp + dataid).attr('rel', not + temp);
    }
    return not + temp;
}

// usage always both together:
change(lastState);       // to reset the last state
lastState = change(REL); // call change and save the actual state
```

Comment: @nina-scholz question confusing my mind. What do I need to reverse the process ? For example

`if(REL == 'NotLike'){$('#Like' + dataid).attr('rel', 'Like');} else if(REL =='NotLove') {$('#Love' + dataid).attr('rel', 'Love');} else if(REL == 'NotUnbelievable'){$('#Unbelievable' + dataid).attr('rel', 'Unbelievable');} else if(REL == 'NotSpectacular'){$('#Spectacular' + dataid).attr('rel','Spectacular');} else if(REL == 'NotEmotional'){$('#Emotional' + dataid).attr('rel', 'Emotional');}`

Comment: @nina-scholz Your answer is working perfectly but i need to learn how can i use it reverse the process ? I need help here :/ .

Comment: you take the part you need and check if the string starts with `Not`: `var temp = REL.substring(3);
  if (REL.substring(0, 3) === 'Not' && ['Like', 'Love', 'Unbelievable', 'Spectacular', 'Emotional'].indexOf(temp) !== -1) {
   $('#' + temp + dataid).attr('rel', temp);
  }`

Comment: @NinaScholz I do not want to bore you :( But i have one last question. If i click `#Like1` then the rel will changing `rel="NotLike"` but after that if i click `#love1` then how can i change `rel="NotLike"` to `rel="Like"` ? Please do not be mad at me.

Comment: @NinaScholz I mean for example: `if (['Like', 'Love', 'Unbelievable','Spectacular', 'Emotional'].indexOf(REL) !== -1) {$('#' + REL + dataid).attr('rel', 'Not' + REL); /////////////////if($('#Love' + dataid).attr('rel', 'NotLove');){$('#Love' + dataid).attr('rel', 'Love');}}` or others.

Comment: @DevStud, i had to go to bed, do you need a flip-flop? notX -> X and X -> notX?

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes i need this :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110795/discussion-between-devstud-and-nina-scholz).